# MPI trouble with routing and ORTE

Tags: mpi

I am working in a code that has been parallelized, it works well, but one of the nodes returns a weird error which I can not figure out how to solve:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE does not know how to route a message to the specified daemon
located on the indicated node:

  my node:   raspberrypi
  target node:  169.254.10.110

This is usually an internal programming error that should be
reported to the developers. In the meantime, a workaround may
be to set the MCA param routed=direct on the command line or
in your environment. We apologize for the problem.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It occurs when executing `mpirun -host 169.254.10.110:1 ptmm` in the shell. With all the other nodes it works perfectly.
The weird thing is that I can reach the node if I do ping -IP but the MPI program apparently can not. The problem suggests me a solution but does not seem to work: `mpirun --mca routed direct -host 169.254.10.110:1 ptmm`. I know it does not work because the same message is still displayed when executed, so either I am writing the command wrong or it really does not solve my problem.

Not only this, but also, will this still work if in the future I want to use the same code and command if I send it by wifi instead of ethernet?

Thanks!

Comment: that can happen if a node has unreachable ip interfaces. If you know `169.254.10.0/24` works with both interfaces (e.g. no firewall and no NAT), you can try `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include 169.254.10.2/24 --host 169.254.10.110:1 hostname` to double check OOB connectivity works fine.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hi, it returned me the next message: `WARNING: An invalid value was given for oob_tcp_if_include.  This
value will be ignored.

  Local host: raspberrypi
  Value:      169.254.10.2/24
  Message:    Did not find interface matching this subnet
----
None of the TCP networks specified to be included for out-of-band communications could be found:` Is it possible that the command lacks of the value of the parameter? Thanks!

Comment: what are the ip/masks of your head node (on which `mpirun` is invoked) and your raspberry pi?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet my Raspberry Pi: 169.254.81.100/16, The Raspberry Pi that has the issue 169.254.10.110/16. All the other RPis work perfectly, and I do not know if there is some problem of configuration in this one (I have received all of them with everything installed and configured)

Comment: in this case, try `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include 169.254.0.0/16 --host 169.254.10.110:1 hostname`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hi, sorry for the late response, it keeps displaying the same error message. Thanks!